# Change of Basis, Linear Algebra,

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a basis B of R3 given by $v_1$ = e1, $v_2$ is the unit vector that makes an angle of 120◦ with $v_1$ in the x−y plane, and $v_3$ is the unit vector that makes an angle of 45◦ with $v_1$ in the x−z plane. Find the matrix of change of basis from the standard basis E to B.

$B=EP$ where E is standard basis matrix, whose columns will comprise of 3 unit vectors, and E = Identity matrix, in last, and P will be equal to B itself, but i am having trouble visualizing $v_2$ and $v_3$ and how one will compute these w.r.t $v_1$

Comment: Hint: If you express the three vectors in coordinates relative to $E$, then $[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ is the change-of-basis matrix from $B$ to $E$. What do you do to this matrix to reverse the direction of the transformation?

Comment: can you please give detailed explaination